# Revoke permission before performing test in Espresso Android

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

I need to revoke Camera permission before performing each Espresso test.
I tried below ways

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
       getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand(
               "pm clear " + getTargetContext().getPackageName());
   }
```

It's revoking permission, but it crashed the app.

I also tried navigate to Settings->Permissions using UiAutomator. But still I can't uncheck the switch.

I understand we can click the Switch (but if the switch is already in OFF state the click made it ON). So, we can't perform click without checking state of the switch. I tried some ways to check the state of the switch if it OFF. But can't make it.

Anyone came across the same scenario? or any help?

Comment: Might be helpful. See this https://github.com/ahasbini/AndroidTestMockPermissionUtils/blob/master/README.md